# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: odoo

I want to ask. The error I get when I do a query to the database

```
def onchange_dept_from(self, cr, uid, ids, partner):
    print partner
    if partner != False:
        # note
        cr.execute('select z.name, z.id from res_partner x, account_account z where x.property_deposit_receivable = z.id AND x.id=%s',(partner,)),
        temp = cr.fetchone()
        name = temp and temp[0] or None

        cr.execute('select z.name, z.id from res_partner x, account_account z where x.property_deposit_payable = z.id AND x.id=%s',(partner,)),
        ads = cr.fetchone()
        name2 = ads and ads[0] or None

        val = {
            'dept_from':name,
            'dept_to':name2,
        }
        return {'value':val }
```

the possibility of "id" that clash came from the function that I use to move into account.move

```
def get_move_line(self, cr, uid, deposit, type, context=None):
    return {
            'type': type,
            'name': deposit.name or 'add',
            'debit': type == 'dest' and deposit.amount or 0.0,
            'credit': type == 'src' and deposit.amount or 0.0,
            'account_id': type == 'src' and deposit.dept_from.id or deposit.dept_to.id,
            'date': deposit.date,
            'deposit_id': deposit.id
    }
```

I think probably because at the time I had to query string, while the function get_move. I am looking for an integer. What should I do? I am out of ideas. please help me

Comment: post your traceback to show where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. I just add query for search the id.

```
def get_move_line(self, cr, uid, deposit, type, context=None):
    cr.execute('select b.property_deposit_payable, b.property_deposit_receivable from deposit_travel a, res_partner b where a.partner = b.id and b.id = %s',(deposit.partner.id,)),
    tmp = cr.fetchone()
    dep_pay = tmp and tmp[0] or None 
    dep_rec = tmp and tmp[1] or None
    return {
            'type': type,
            'name': deposit.name or 'add',
            'debit': type == 'dest' and deposit.amount or 0.0,
            'credit': type == 'src' and deposit.amount or 0.0,
            'account_id': type == 'src' and dep_pay or dep_rec,
            'date': deposit.date,
            'deposit_id': deposit.id
```